# Not able to Remove Add-on from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

A user of one of my Google sheets add-ons wants to remove it. He has followed the correct procedure to do so but it keeps appearing in his list of add-ons when he opens sheets. He tells me it has not been installed by the admin for his domain. I can't work out what if anything I can do to help him remove it. Any advice?

This is a video illustrating the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M4WYGTwLzTWcYmrFf_SGFEn8Lv8OGbj6/view

Answer (score 0):

They should make sure it's not also installed in the G Suite Marketplace: https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/lntol_sheet_translator/1054412249402

This is a known issue that we will be fixing with the upcoming Chrome Web Store to G Suite Marketplace migration: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration